# Why would a copied rm executable not work on another linux machine?

Tags: linux, command-line

I have copied the rm executable from my machines "/bin/rm" to another linux machine that happens to be so minimal that it does not include the rm command.
When I tried to execute the rm command I got this error:

```
/bin/rm: /bin/rm: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Why won't it work? How could I "add" the rm functionality to this box?
(This box does not have a package manager install either.)

Comment: Does this box have `unlink` ? `busybox` ?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't have unlink

Comment: What are the two Linuxes? If the `rm` is linked to libraries that do not exist on the other machine, or to the wreng versions of them, you'll get errors.

Comment: What CPUs do both Linux systems have?

Comment: My system in Debian and the other one is a Wind River embedded linux

Comment: @Kusulananda GNU `rm` only needs a libc, and if it's built with glibc it only needs version 2.14 (2011). The error suggests an architecture mismatch instead.

Comment: @StephenKitt I'm slightly surprised that `/bin` (and presumably `/sbin`) binaries are not compiled as static binaries... But this (the Q) is probably a matter of an architecture mismatch.

Comment: @Kusalananda yeah, some distributions used to have some statically linked binaries for `rm` and such like (to allow recovery from deleting libraries), but systems are now complex enough that the answer is just "use a recovery system" nowadays.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`rm` is a binary file and therefore architecture dependent. It would only work if you copy from the same architecture and with the same required libraries installed.

Alternatively, you can compile it from [source code](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) or install the binary package. In Debian systems, it's a [package](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=coreutils).

In case you already have a binary and want to know its architecture, use `file` or `objdump` commands.

Comment: Anyway to "install" the rm command to a particular architecture?
Is there a process to do it properly?
Can I compile it from source or something?

Comment: @JoaquínGumucio I have updated my answer.